# How to contact Microsoft about an issue with Visual Studio Marketplace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I want to publish a maintenance update to a VSCode extension that I once published.

I published the extension while I was at university X, and now I am at university Y. Stupidly, I had used my university X email address for creating the Azure DevOps account for publishing the extension, and this email address does no longer exist, so I lost access to the Azure DevOps account. I still have access to the Github account of the source repository of the extension, so I can "prove" that I am the author.

I believe that as the author of an extension with a few hundred users it is well in the interest of Microsoft to support me with this. The problem is that since I am not a business customer of Microsoft, *I see no way to contact them at all.* **Does someone have a support email address, perhaps?**

If preferred, you can also contact me directly via https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/10190810/david.

Comment: just publish the extension under a different name in the marketplace, `Extname2`

Answer (score 1):

Before following any technical advice, you should first identify if there is any copyright/patent issue you neglected. "I published the extension while I was at university X" might be an indicator of such issues if you were employed in anyway and the actual work contracts might force you to grant copyright to the university. Be warned that some contracts don't even allow you to publish such on your own, so there might be bigger problems (the typical your code is not yours situation).

Once you iron out the non-technical part, it might be a good thing to end that old extension publisher account completely and start all over with a new publisher account.